# Trouble Installing virtualenv on Python 3.5.1 OSX

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I've tried to install virtualenv using `sudo pip install virtualenv` but it's not installing properly. This is what happens when I use `sudo pip install virtualenv` again and then try to get the version of it.
https://gyazo.com/0cbff8acaf8f4fdc505e53913739e28a
https://gyazo.com/9a5917157ac5c6ef44d49c2752f1e113

Comment: You may be installing into Python2, try `sudo pip3 install`

Comment: It doesn't recognize pip3 and I'm pretty sure I set it so pip refers to pip3.5

Comment: Hmm, works on my Mac. Maybe I installed Python3 using homebrew.

Comment: Yeah I used macports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the folder containing virtualenv to your shell's path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/containing/virtualenv/
```

You could also create a symlink to the virtualenv file in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. These two folders are usually in the shell PATH by default:

```
ln -s /path/to/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in this case I would be adding /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages to my path?

Comment: Okay I tried the symlink method and it still isn't working https://gyazo.com/24d49d1ef9e1dc151b97b347d2df3255

Comment: It's still not working https://gyazo.com/a2c6849019d6ef5b6fa1a216054bf391
https://gyazo.com/a2c6849019d6ef5b6fa1a216054bf391

Comment: Try this: `ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-‌​p‌​ackages/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: If there is no virtualenv file(without the extension .py) in the site-packages folder, can you see if that exists somewhere else on your system using `find / -name virtualenv`?

Comment: Did you add a trailing slash to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`? Remove that.

Comment: So I found a version with no .py extension and tried the symlink again and this is what I got:
https://gyazo.com/af7c6223a541903b51112e682ebc9232

Comment: Are you able to execute that virtualenv file you found by giving the full path to it? Just type `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv` on the commandline. Does it show the help for virtualenv?

Comment: Cool :) Let's try creating the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` again. Delete the existing symlink first using `rm /usr/local/bin/virtualenv` and then create it again using `ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: It just says they're not a directory https://gyazo.com/37f1620deb446a9c1bda3ca3e08eec8d

Comment: That's strange. Can you paste the output of `ls -al /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`?

Comment: ls: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: Not a directory

Comment: Are you able to cd into the /usr/local/bin directory? What is the output of `ls -al /usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Also try `unlink /user/local/bin/virtualenv`.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5e6d110fe738dee9d2e6432fa9f5dbfe and the unlink just gives me no directory or file

Comment: Hmm. That's the problem. The `/usr/local/bin` directory has been symlinked to the .py file. I think that happened because you ran ln -n with the `/usr/local/bin` argument instead of `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. But...this should not have happened if the `/usr/local/bin` directory already existed before you ran the ln command. Are you sure that it did?

Comment: Yeah that directory did exist beforehand

Comment: Well, I'm quite stumped. It is impossible for it to have allowed you to link a file to a directory. If any commands existed earlier in `/usr/local/bin` they wouldn't be working now if that was allowed...

Comment: So hypothetically if it didn't exist, what would I do?

Comment: You'd then unlink `/usr/local/bin` using `unlink /usr/local/bin`. Then create a **directory** called bin in there using `mkdir /usr/local/bin`. Then create the symlink to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. And finally, add /usr/local/bin to your shell's PATH variable.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for all the help it really helped.